# SQLite DISTINCT with Sorting

Tags: sqlite, distinct

I have a "`messages`" table with the following columns:

- `id` (primary Key)
- `username`
- `timestamp`
- `content`

I want to get a list of distinct usernames sorted by their latest message. I get the DISTINCT part but don't know how to make it return the one with the latest `timestamp`. I only have this so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT username FROM messages
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd approach this slightly differently:

```
SELECT username 
FROM messages
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY MAX(timestamp)
```

Comment: Wow. Interesting approach. I am going to try this now!!

Answer (score 0):

put

```
  order by timestamp.
```

at the end. If you want the latest first you should put

```
  order by timestamp desc
```

at the end

Comment: Hi Daniel, I will give it a try but wouldn't that sort by whatever timestamp it got. How do I control which timestamp to pick for that distinct username.